# Samsung dex and remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control, remote-assistance

I am using aws wrorkspaces to connect from from dex to the pc. It works great in resolution. I am unable to this in my own virtual machines. Which remote desktop mobile app should i use ?